# strtok - moving one place forward

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have the function of `myPrint` that I am trying to use but I think that I am using the `strtok` function wrong

```
int myPrint( const  char* format , ...)
{
    char str[BUFFER];
    char cpy[BUFFER] = {0};
    char convert[BUFFER];
    char *check;
    char tempFormat[BUFFER];
    int len = 0;
    char *tempCheck;

    va_list args;
    va_start( args , format);   
    strcpy(tempFormat , format );

    check = strtok ( tempFormat , "%");

    int flag = 0;
    while( check != NULL)
    {
        strcat( cpy , check  );
        len = strlen( cpy );    

        switch(  tempFormat[len + 1]  )
        {
            case 'd':
                    sprintf( convert , "%d" , va_arg( args , int) );
                    strcat( cpy , convert);
                    break;
            case 'f':
                    sprintf( convert , "%f" , va_arg( args, double ));
                    strcat( cpy , convert);
                    break;
            case '%':
                    strcat( cpy ,"%" );
                    break;          
            case 's':
                    strcat( cpy ,va_arg( args , char* ) );
                    break;  
            default:
                break;              
        }
        check = strtok ( NULL  , "%");
    }

    printf("%s" , cpy);
    va_end( args);
}

void main()
{
    int x = 7;
    float y = 11;
    char str[] ="HELLo";
    char str2[]="MY NAME";

    myPrint ( "ss %d is %d %s  " , 7 , 6 , str);
}
```

The problem is if I send to the function to print what I want, I get after each `%` also the `d`

Is there a way to move the result of the `strtok` call one place forward?

Comment: `(check + 1)`??

Comment: if i do it i get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You need to check that you are not at the end and there is actually a character to move to, e.g. `if (*check && *(check + 1)) { /* then use check + 1 (or just check++) */ }`

Comment: did it. didn't help

Comment: we have to guess that `BUFFER` is sufficient to hold `strcpy(tempFormat , format );` Then `check = strtok ( tempFormat , "%");` will *Point To* the characters that make up the string up to the 1st `'%'` char. (`strtok` will replace the `'%'` with `'\0'` during the parse). `If (check && *check && *(check + 1)) { /* then it is fine to use *(check + 1) -- which is the 2nd char in the string pointed to by check */ }`

Comment: The posted code results in the compiler outputting 36 warning and error messages.   TO start, it is missing the needed header files include statements.  `#include <stdio.h>` `#include <string.h>`  `#include <stdarg.h>`

Comment: the function: `myPrint()`  is declared to return an `int`, but the `main()` function is not checking for a returned value.  Suggest changing the return type to `void`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  The macro `BUFFER`  does not indicate its' contents.  Perhaps `BUFFER_LEN` would be more descriptive

Comment: after I inserted the needed header files, and inserted a macro for `BUFFER`, there are still LOTS of problems: , unused variables: `flag`, `tempCheck`,   `str[]`,  `y`, `x`.  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns a type `size_t`, not an `int`, so the declaration of `len` should be `size_t` not `int`

Comment: there are several format specifier characters other than the 4 listed in the function `myPrint()`  There are numerous leading 'modifiers' to those format specifiers, including `numeric value . numeric value` etc etc etc that are not being handled in the posted code.  And since the idea seems to be to 'preprocess' the format string, so it contains the final display string, with no format specifiers,  suggest using `puts()` rather than the current call to `printf()`

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to feed `strtok` a new pointer if you want to move it beyond the last match. I tried your code with the changes below:

Edit:
I updated with the whole code which might be easier for you to see now!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


#define BUFFER 500
int myPrint( const  char* format , ...)
{
    char str[BUFFER];
    char cpy[BUFFER] = {0};
    char convert[BUFFER];
    char *check;
    char *last_check;
    char tempFormat[BUFFER];
    int len = 0;
    char *tempCheck;

    va_list args;
    va_start( args , format);   
    strcpy(tempFormat , format );

    check = strtok (tempFormat , "%");

    int flag = 0;
    while( check != NULL)
    {
        strcat( cpy , check  );
        len = strlen(cpy);    

        switch(  tempFormat[len + 1]  )
        {
            case 'd':
                    sprintf( convert , "%d" , va_arg( args , int) );
                    strcat( cpy , convert);
                    break;
            case 'f':
                    sprintf( convert , "%f" , va_arg( args, double ));
                    strcat( cpy , convert);
                    break;
            case '%':
                    strcat( cpy ,"%" );
                    break;          
            case 's':
                    strcat( cpy ,va_arg( args , char* ) );
                    break;  
            default:
                break;              
        }
        int len = strlen(check);
        last_check = check;
        check = strtok (check+len+2 , "%");
    }

    strcat( cpy , last_check);
    printf("%s" , cpy);
    va_end( args);
}

void main()
{
    int x = 7;
    float y = 11;
    char str[] ="HELLo";
    char str2[]="MY NAME";

    myPrint ("ss %d is %d %s  " , 7 , 6 , str);
}
```

Comment: i tried what you wrote but it didn't help to solve the problem

Comment: It worked from my side. Could you report what was the output you got? I skipped the declaration of `last_check` only!

Comment: Also, be sure to delete the line `check = strtok ( NULL  , "%");` as this was replaced.

Comment: i did cop paste to your code and after the second %d its printing nonsense. i think i replace the strtok and think of something new.